Unable to find image locally docker: Error response from daemon: {"message":"connection refused"}
I've been using docker several time from my company computer but not continiously and never had any problem before. Today i try to run this command(from windows cmd) :
docker run -d --name redisinsight -p 5540:5540 redis/redisinsight:latest

And I got this error:

Unable to find image 'redis/redisinsight:latest' locally docker: Error
response from daemon: {"message":"connection refused"}. See 'docker
run --help'.

I try to run other images and got the same results.

This doesn't seem like a programming-related problem.  The "connection refused" image could mean that the Docker daemon isn't running, or docker context is pointed at somewhere that doesn't make sense, or you have the DOCKER_HOST environment variable set incorrectly; or it could also mean your system has network connectivity issues.  None of these will be problems with your application source code though.
